# conversion issue from a Label to int for an ID key

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got problem converting this car id key from a label.  Here is the error I am receiving

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField'
>   to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'.

Do you have any suggestion to avoid this error ?

Thanks

```
Label myCarId = (Label)item.FindControl("carId");
iCarId = Convert.ToInt32(myCarId);
Session["carId"] = iCarId;
```

Comment: Apparently `carID`ain't a label, but a hidden field instead.

Comment: The `carId` control is not a `Label`, it's a `HiddenField`. It's also not convertable to an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
HiddenField myCarId = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("carId");
iCarId = Convert.ToInt32(myCarId.Value);
Session["carId"] = iCarId;
```

Comment: Posted same solution at same moment :) removed mine it was useless.

Comment: oh realy? i didn't notice it. Thumb up buddy. You shouldn't remove it. You also deserve vote up for it.

Comment: `TryParse` would be safer.

Comment: Yup, voted up.. Just was trying to correct error in OP current code. @MikeSmithDev

Answer (score 1):

```
HiddenField myCarId = item.FindControl("carId") as HiddenField;
iCarId = Convert.ToInt32(myCarId.Value);
Session["carId"] = iCarId;
```

Label can not be convert as int because it's a control. But it's text can be convert which is string.

Answer (score 0):

The Error message suggests that carId is a hidden field so if you want a label you would need to change that in the aspx/asmx page. A Label is not a primitive, I think what you are after is `Label.Text` also when it comes to conversion I would prefer int.TryParse instead of convert as it doesn't throw an exception when the conversion fails.

```
Label myCarId = (Label)item.FindControl("carId");
int iCarId;
int.TryParse(myCarId.Text,out iCarId);
Session["carId"] = iCarId;
```